# Deprecated iamRoleStatements on Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless

Today I tried to deploy an update on a serverless js based project. The problem is that the lambdas are not logging anymore (can't see any invocation or another metric on the Serverless Dashboard).
When deploying the project I get a warning reading:

> Warning: Lambda log collection is not supported in us-east-1

Then, when I run `serverless doctor` I get this output:

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules
1 deprecation triggered in the last command:

Starting with version 4.0.0, following property will be replaced:
  "provider.iamRoleStatements" -> "provider.iam.role.statements"
More info: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#PROVIDER_IAM_SETTINGS_V3
```

Regarding that message, this is my configuration on the serverless.yml:

```
...
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:*
      Resource: 
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTable
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTypeTable
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTypeTable/index/*
...
```

And of course, if I simply change the line `iamRoleStatements:` for `iam.role.statements:` I get this:

```
Error:
Configuration error at 'provider': unrecognized property 'iam.role.statements'
```

I am fairly new working with Serverless, so my questions are:
Could this deprecation be causing my serverless dashboard to not display any metrics?
How do I properly update my serverless.yml file according to the error message I got from the `serverless doctor` command?

---

EDIT:
I solved the deprecation warning like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: us-east-1
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:*
          Resource: 
            - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTable
            - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTypeTable
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
          Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:table/observationTypeTable/index/*
```

But the lambdas still are unable to log.